Docker build - failed to fetch anonymous token - proxyconnect tcp
I'm trying to build an image from an AWS Lambda python base image via a VPN, as I'm behind the GFW.
I run the build command:
docker build --progress=plain --platform="linux/x86_64" --no-cache -t projects/my-project . -f projects/my-project/Dockerfile

But I get the following error:
ERROR: failed to solve: public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11: failed to resolve source metadata for public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11: failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: Get "https://public.ecr.aws/token/?scope=aws%3A%3A&scope=repository%3Alambda%2Fpython%3Apull&service=public.ecr.aws": proxyconnect tcp: EOF

I am able to follow the link in my browser to view the token, but Docker is unable retrieve it. The line that fails is the first line in the Dockerfile:
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11
I am able to pull the image successfully with: docker pull public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11
I have set up my proxy settings in /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf:
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:7890/"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://127.0.0.1:7890/"

I have also set up a named DNS server (1.1.1.1) in etc/resolv.conf:
# Google DNS
# nameserver 8.8.8.8
# nameserver 8.8.4.4

# Cloudflare DNS
nameserver 1.1.1.1

# nameserver 127.0.0.53

IE I can run nslookup example.com to get:
Server:         1.1.1.1
Address:        1.1.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   example.com
Address: 93.184.215.14
Name:   example.com
Address: 2606:2800:21f:cb07:6820:80da:af6b:8b2c

I can also run dig example.com to get:
; <<>> DiG 9.18.28-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 4358
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.                   IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.            2768    IN      A       93.184.215.14

;; Query time: 392 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Wed Aug 14 12:28:57 CST 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56

I have tried running the build with --network=host which is still unsuccessful. I have also tried running with docker buildx build, but this is also unsuccessful.
I have proxies for http, https, socks5, mixed, and redirect ports. Besides this Docker pull issue, the VPN works as intended.
Docker usage has been affected recently due to GFW (https://medium.com/@PlanB./chinese-docker-hub-complete-shutdown-how-far-can-kubernetes-image-repositories-go-826706007b8e).
Any help appreciated!
UPDATE:
After correcting the proxy settings in /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf (use http not https protocol for both env vars) to:
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:7890/"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:7890/"

I am able to run the first step of pulling the base image. However, the subsequent yum update -y step fails:
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y curl pip nano
RUN yum clean -y all

It produces the following:
#6 [ 2/14] RUN yum update -y
#6 0.235 Loaded plugins: ovl
#6 0.253 Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://amazonlinux.default.amazonaws.com/2/core/latest/x86_64/mirror.list error was
#6 0.253 14: curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 7890 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server"

It seems the docker build process is still struggling to reach out through the VPN.

The solution is to specify the proxy in the build command, as well as the --network flag:
docker build --network="host" --build-arg="https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:7890" --progress=plain --platform="linux/x86_64" --no-cache -t projects/my-project . -f projects/my-project/Dockerfile


You can also just pull the image, and docker will use it as a cached image if you just want to test locally:
docker pull public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11
